# SpringBoot сохраняет два объекта вместо редактирования одного

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, save

Здравствуйте, столкнулась с интересной проблемой.
Согласно документации `save` метод для `SpringBoot` может как сохранить новый объект, так и редактировать уже сохранненый. 
Проблема следующая: когда я пытаюсь редактировать объект, springboot редактирует данный объект и затем дублирует старый и тоже сохраняет его. 
Как можно увидеть из примера, объект который я редактирую, сначала находится с помощью id
К примеру,

```
Question qq = questionRepository.findQuestionById(id);
qq.setPicture(filename);
questionRepository.save(qq);
```

Выдает в итоге в базе данных:

```
id: 1, name: test, picture: testpicture
```

и

```
id: 2, name: test, picture: NULL
```

Comment: Там нужно использовать метод метод update(qq) а не save(qq)

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-
Согласно документации, этот метод сохраняет новый обьект в базе, а не обновляет старый.

Comment: Николай, насколько я вижу, метода update вообще нет.

Comment: @aleshka-batman , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43719828/update-or-saveorupdate-in-crudrepository . `CrudRepository has only save but it acts as update as well. When you do save on entity with existing id it will do an update`  Я точно знаю что save выполняет две функции

Comment: И в ссылке, которую вы прикрепили тоже об этом написано

Comment: Скорее всего вы проводите изменения внутри транзакции с включенным параметром "автофиксации" (что нибудь из области FlushMode, хотя может быть и иной). Данные поведение не свойственно для настроек по умолчанию, видимо сами прописали.

Comment: Я посмотрела, либо я не замечаю очевидного, либо я просто не понимаю, где я могла поменять данную настройку.

Comment: Самое инересное, что для другого оюъекта все работает идеально

Comment: Попробуй составить сокращенную версию приложения, в которой данная ситуация будет воспроизводиться (или выложите полный проект через git-hub. Если этого не запрещает политика). И опишите шаги для воспроизведения исключительной ситуации.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все оказалось намного проще. Надо было быть мне внимательнее. Правильный ответ опубликован) и извиняюсь за беспокойноство.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка оказалось очень глупой. я поставила аннотацию cascade.ALL и сохраняла одновременно два объекта : parent и child. в итоге, child сохранялся два раза.